# Help opening GIS files

Tags: file-formats, format

I was given 8 files that supposedly contain GIS data. They appear to be a file split into parts and are named: "stuff.zip [1_8].dat" , "stuff.zip [2_8].dat" , etc..

I tried stripping the ".dat" but that didn't help to unzip the files. I know this is probably a zip problem rather than GIS problem but I was hoping someone might recognize how the heck someone would send GIS data in this form. Opening with a text editor shows the following type of data, any idea if this is an old ESRI file type that was given the wrong extension or something? Thanks for any ideas.

> UEsDBBQAAgAIAJlIQTmhyPOiMJdSALDsUgAXAAAAU2V3ZXJfSW52ZW50b3J5X01hcC5wZGYAM4DM
>   fyVQREYtMS41DQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PA0KL0xlbmd0aCAyIDAgUg0KL0ZpbHRlciAgL0ZsYXRlRGVj
>   b2RlDQo+Pg0Kc3RyZWFtDQp4nOy8WbOqSNcuej8j/A8LUBBQ6QUVe7ABGxCxp7FB7BGbc2LXxfnt

---

Edit: it looks like this is a problem with how the data was encoded for the email message? After searching around a bit, I'm not sure how to deal with this. Obviously this is in the completely wrong forum at this point but thanks for any help. Here is a header before the alphanumeric string begins:

> Content-Type: application/octet-stream;
>       name="stuff.zip"
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
>   Content-Disposition: attachment;
>       filename="stuff.zip"

Comment: Looks like it's a single zip split over many files.  7 zip or winRAR can normally open those.

Comment: Yea, unfortunately I can't get them to unzip. Oh well, just thought maybe they were named incorrectly and were actually some sort of GIS filetype. Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because, although it originally seemed to be about GIS, it turned out to concern e-mail encoding and zip formats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use 7zip, can only comment on using that to reassemble split archive.

All 8 files must be in the same directory. I just created a split archive of 14 parts (10 MB each) from one image gallery (140 MB) and then put it back together to test the process.

Select first file (stuff.zip.[1_8].dat in your case), right click, select 7zip, "Extract to".

If that does not work, create a backup of your 8 files and try removing .dat part from all the file names and then reassembling the archive.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I was able to recombine into a single file, but 7-zip still can not open the file. I guess because it is just plain text? Not sure what to use to decode into something useful.

Thanks for the help recombining the file though

Comment: Does that recombined file have an extension? It might not be an archive, it could be the actual file, but with lost extension.

Comment: I renamed the files to end with ".zip.001" ".zip.002" etc.. Then opened the 001 file with 7zip. That gave me the combined .zip file.

Comment: @RossV 
A google search just lead me to this tool which can be used to identify files with no extension: http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html
Have not used it myself, but looks promising. Maybe give it a shot.

Comment: http://mark0.net/soft-tridnet-e.html for the version with GUI. TrIDNet and the "TrID XML defs" must be put in the same directory.

Comment: This was a perfect tool to solve this problem! Thanks you!

Comment: @RossV Glad to help. Accept this answer if you want. Question will probably be migrated to some other site though, since it is not related to GIS.

Answer (score 0):

If you use 7zip and select the correct option it will merge your dat file chunks

Comment: Care to elaborate further on "the correct option", maybe a screenshot or two?

Comment: comments above contain the correct answer; put files in same folder, double click first file, when asked by windows what program to use select 7zip.